# BottomNavigationView using androidx

Tags: android, androidx, bottomnavigationview, material-components, material-components-android

I have created some app and I had like to insert to it a BottomNavigationView.

The code worked perfectly however once I changed at my gradle to androidx it stopped working.

The component in my layout (activity_about):

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorWhite"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_foreground"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_foreground" />
```

The menu file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_library"
    android:enabled="true"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Library"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_search"
    android:enabled="true"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
    android:enabled="true"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"/>
</menu>
```

The drawable file (bottom_navigation_foreground):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/colorPurpleFont" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/Gray"  />
</selector>
```

and my code is as follows:

```
public class AboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_library:
                        startActivity(new Intent(AboutActivity.this, DiscoverActivity.class));
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_search:
                        Toast.makeText(AboutActivity.this, "Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_profile:
                        Toast.makeText(AboutActivity.this, "Nearby", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any reason it is not working since I changed to androidx?

Thank you

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Using androidx you have to switch to [**`BottomNavigationView`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomNavigationView.md) in the [Material components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Add the [dependency](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#1-depend-on-our-library) in `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
   //..
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
}
```

use a [material theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme) and add in your layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
 .../>
```

Answer (score 4):

i have solved same problem by replacing

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

>
```

**change it to and also implement the dependencies too**

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        >
```

**in build.gradle**

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
```

**refer android documentation**
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView